# VBA runtime error 91 even though variable is set

Tags: vba

I am struggling with a piece of code that places a custom class in a collection.  Every time I run the code I get a runtime error 91.  The error is occuring on the Set pjt = New CProject line.

```
Dim Projects As Collection

Private Sub BuildProjects()
   Dim pjt As CProject
   Set Projects = New Collection
   Set pjt = New CProject   '<-----ERROR OCCURS HERE

   'Do some other stuff

End Sub
```

This is obviously the simplest form of the Sub, but it still throws the error!  What am I doing wrong?  Do I need to set the access for the CProject class file somehow?

All your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can we see the code inside the constructor of CProject?

Answer (score 2):

The line `Set pjt = New CProject` is calling the constructor for CProject.

The error will most likely be in the constructor of CProject.

Error 91 is a null reference